# How to allow ssh access to a folder of another user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, sftp, sshd

Let's say I have a user 'user1'. This user has a special directory which can be accessed by another user ('user2'): `/home/user1/directory`

How can I allow ssh/sftp access for user2 only to this directory? so when user2 connects 
to the server via SSH/SFTP the /home/user1/directory is opened and only this directory could be accessed. user2 must have all kind of permissions within this folder only.

I was thinking about granting 777 permissions to this folder and creating a bash script to redirect to the folder but I'm not sure if this is a correct way.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue myself by the means of `ChrootDirectory`.

Here is sshd_condig:

```
Match user user2
        ChrootDirectory /home/user2/lock
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        GatewayPorts no
```

And I created a symlink that links `/home/user2/lock` with `/home/user1/directory`

The other solution was to change the owner of the `/home/user1/directory` to root and specify this directory as chroot'ed directory but that's not quite convenient in my case.
Hope this will help if somebody meet the issue in the future.